# Initializing Google Passportjs strategy error

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I have recently switched a server project from javascript to typescript and am in the process of cleaning up some code. I used to keep some google passport Oauth stuff and login routes in separate files but decided to combine them. In the process I have broken some code and don't understand why the error is occurring or how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

I know that the error occurs in index.ts on the `server.express.use(auth.initialize())` line. I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined` Can you help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

**index.ts**

```
import { createTypeormConn } from './db/createConn'
import schema from './graphql'
import { pubsub } from './graphql/PubSub'
import * as auth from './middleware/auth'
const express = require('express')
const { GraphQLServer, PubSub } = require('graphql-yoga')
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

export const startServer = async () => {
    await createTypeormConn()
    const corsOptions = {
        origin: [
            //omitted for brevity
        ],
        credentials: true
    }

    const options = {
        port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
        endpoint: '/api',
        subscriptions: '/api',
        playground: '/playground'
    }

    const server = new GraphQLServer({
        schema,
        context: req => ({ pubsub, request: req.request })
    })

    server.express.use(
        cookieSession({
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            keys: [''] //omitted
        })
    )

    server.use(cors(corsOptions))
    server.express.options('/api', cors(corsOptions))
    server.express.use(auth.initialize()) //fails during initialize
    server.express.use(auth.session())
    server.express.use('/auth', auth.routes)
    server.express.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'site')))
    server.start(options, ({ port }) => {
        console.log(`Server is running on localhost:${port}`)
    })
}
startServer()
```

**auth.ts**

```
import { User } from '../db/orm'
import * as passport from 'passport'
import { Router } from 'express'
import { OAuth2Strategy } from 'passport-google-oauth'

passport.serializeUser<any, any>((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findOne(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user)
    })
})

passport.use(
    new OAuth2Strategy(
        {
            callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
            clientID:'', //omitted
            clientSecret: '' //omitted
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            //omitted
            return done(null, user)
        }
    )
)

const routes = Router()

routes.get('/google/start', (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile'],
        state: req.query.stream
    } as any)(req, res)
})

routes.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    //omitted    
})

const initialize = passport.initialize
const session = passport.session
export { initialize, session, routes }
```

Comment: To get some more information, add `console.log(auth)` above the definition of `startServer` and again just before the line throwing the error.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen both console logs yield identical results. The console prints an object: ```{ routes: {//brevity}, initialize: [Function], session: [Function]```

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Also, if I use VSCode debugger to step into the initialize method the last line contains ```return this._framework.initialize(this, options)``` and it appears that _framework is ```undefined```. Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for your help Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the `this` context of `passport`.  Replace:

```
const initialize = passport.initialize
const session = passport.session
```

with:

```
const initialize = passport.initialize.bind(passport)
const session = passport.session.bind(passport)
```

Comment: great thinking Matt.